# Hive - Error in acquiring locks

Tags: transactions, hive, locking

Hive is aborting execution and logging:

```
No rows affected (0.005 seconds)
No rows affected (0.059 seconds)
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Locks on the underlying objects cannot be acquired. retry after some time (state=42000,code=10)

Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://
```

Can someone give some tip how to troubleshoot this?

> hive version is 0.14 in a horton distribution 
>   hive.support.concurrency=true;  hive.txn.manager=DummyTxnManager

Comment: Run `show locks ;` then try to understand who, or what, is locking your target table. Could be a crashed JDBC client from Windows -- for some reason JDBC-on-Windows maintains a keep-alive even after the client has died *(known issue with Oracle, etc.)* and you must close the Windows session to release the connection and the locks.

Comment: Or, the metastore DB could be running slooooow -- look at the Metastore service logs. Look into the "timeout" properties. The defaults may have changed with 0.13 or 0.14 (sthg I vaguely recall now...)

Answer (score 11):

Set this property and run it.

SET hive.support.concurrency=false;

By default it is true.

Nitish

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, queries can lead to dead lock. I suggest having a closer look at your query to identify any dead lock pattern.

The [locking documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking) might help.

I don't suggest disabling the concurrency but instead, using the [configuration documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Locking) customize

> hive.lock.numretries
>
> hive.unlock.numretries
>
> hive.lock.sleep.between.retries